# Node.JS and AngularJS Routes with API routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-route

So I am using Node.JS with Express as my backend and my servlet for API. I'm using AngularJS as my front end.

Through many Google searches, I finally solved my problem of using `ngRoute` with AngularJS and Node.js. And ended up with this:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var auth  = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use('/api/auth', auth);
app.use('/', index);
app.use('*', index);
```

This is of course an excerpt of my app.js file at the root of my project.

Now when I make a call to my `/api/auth/` I get told that node.js can't find my view. If I remove the `app.use('*', index)` the API works again but 'ngRoute' doesn't work.

How can I get to a point where both are working together? I also want to keep the address bar url as clean as possible.

My project was started with a call to `yo node` using `yeoman` if that helps any in the file/folder structure of my application.

**Update**

I'm not getting any answers or comments so maybe providing my full `app.js` file will be helpful and help me figure this out. Here it is.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var auth = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

app.use('/', index);
app.use('*', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Update 2**

I have come to notice that the statement "ngRoute doesn't work" is vague. If I remove `app.use('*', index)` I receive this error if I try to go to an address other than the base address. **I also receive this error when trying to access the`api/auth`**

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/mitch/websites/splatform/views"
```

**Update 3**

The index.js file that my routes in app.js refer to includes this as well.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'index.html'));
});
```

But, API calls shouldn't be going to the index.js File. Should be going to Auth.js.

**Update 4**

As requested, here is my `$routeProvider` from AngularJS.

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                resolve: {
                    lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load ('frontStyles');
                    }]
                }
            })
            .when('/app/login', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                resolve: {
                    lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load ('appStyles', 'appScripts');
                    }]
                }
            })
            .when('/app/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
                resolve: {
                    lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load ('appStyles', 'appScripts');
                    }]
                }
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Also here is a simple run down of my file structure

```
app.js
routes
  --auth.js
  --index.js
views
  --index.html ( angularJS Base )
public
  --directives
  --fonts
  --images
  --javascripts
  --stylesheets
  --templates ( Views that angularjs uses in `ng-view`
```

Comment: This is a ***very well documented*** process.  There have been many questions almost identical to this posted here.  What *specifically* makes your question different from any of those?  Also, what does "ngRoute doesn't work" actually mean?  Error messages? unexpected behavior?

Comment: I spent all day yesterday googling for results. Tried multiple instances and nothing seemed to make it "work" (ngroute didn't work or api didn't work). "ngRoute doesn't work" means when I try to go anywhere other than the base address ('/') such as ('/login') I get an error that states the view couldn't be found.

Comment: what is the path to one of the view files?

Comment: also, I assume that you are using `html5Mode` in Angular?  you haven't really shown any of your angular code....

Comment: @Claies the path of the view files if /views/ however the view path for angularjs is /public/templates/ The only file in /views/ is the base index.html for Angularjs

Comment: @Claies I do apologize, I am trying to help as much as possible. Yes, I am using `html5Mode` in Angular.

Comment: it doesn't look like you have an express route for the template files.  You may want to take a look at this FAQ from the 3rd party ui-router.  It's not *specifically* about ng-route, but ui-router is a drop in replacement, so if it works for ui-router, it will definitely work with ng-route.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: also, http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express

Comment: Check my updated question.

Comment: Also, I shouldn't need a specific route for template files as they are listed in public. My css/javascript/images etc are all in public and they work just fine?

Comment: again, you aren't showing any angular code here, so it's not obvious what files angular is trying to request from the server.  clearly you have a bit of confusion about it yourself, since you said that your angular templates are in `/public/templates`, but the error you have in the question suggests angular was requesting a file from `/views`...

Comment: @Claies No need to get snarky, I'm trying to help so I can learn. I've updated my question with some angular code and a base file structure.

Comment: So what address did you go to that generated `Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/mitch/websites/splatform/views"`?  None of the angular code you listed here should be causing an `error` view to be loaded?

Comment: Copied directly from the address bar: http://localhost:3000/app/login

Comment: and don't you want `/public/templates/home.html` (for example), rather than `templates/home.html`?

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in the `app.js` file grabs it and directs it accordingly.

Comment: @Claies I tried adding public/ to my `$routeProvider` and it changed nothing.

Comment: It actually wasn't a problem with routing at all. Just issues with error reporting and what Node.js was returning to angular. Should I delete this question or what?

Comment: Hello! Have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Call api's routes first then angularjs index.

For example: **routesWeb.js**

```
    'use strict';
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');

    module.exports = function(app) {

        var path_web = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
        var path_origin = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

        app.use('/scripts',express.static(path_web + '/scripts'));
        app.use('/pages',express.static(path_web + '/pages'));
        app.use('/node_modules',express.static(path_origin + '/node_modules'));

        app.route('/*')
        .get(function(req, res){
            res.sendFile(path_web + '/pages/ng-index.html');
        });
    }
```

**pessoaRota.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {

    var pessoasCtrl = require('../controllers/pessoasController');  

    app.route('/api/pessoas')
        .get(pessoasCtrl.obter_todos_pessoas);

    app.route('/api/pessoas/:pessoaId')
        .get(pessoasCtrl.obter_pessoa_por_id);

    app.route('/api/pessoasFeias')
        .get(pessoasCtrl.obter_pessoas_feias);

};
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());


var server = app.listen(port, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Aplicação está on nesse endereço http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

require('./api/routes/pessoaRota.js')(app);
require('./web/routes/routesWeb.js')(app);
```

For more go [here](https://github.com/filipeassad/rotas-angularjs-com-rotas-api-nodejs).